# Как правильно работать с React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Смотрел мануалы по React, из них сложилось впечатление, что при открытии страницы в браузере, с сервера должен приходить не html, а только данные, которые потом получает React и отрисовывает с помощью jsx в html, так и нужно делать, это не отнимет слишком много ресурсов на клиенте? Или всё таки с сервера как обычно лучше отдавать нормальную html страницу, и уже потом по мере необходимости, компонентами менять её на клиенте, как обычно?

Comment: если хотите использовать реакт, вам надо определится для чего он нужен. У него есть шаблонизатор, так зачем и там и там рендерить, делить вьюшки на сервере и на клиенте? Не проще ли использовать обычный JS, чтобы его показать на странице? Да, рендеринг на клиенте использует ресурсы, иногда много (особенно при неправильном использовании). Ну так и цель его состоить в Single Page Application.

Comment: А если сайт многостраничный... т.е. пользователь так или иначе переходит по url и вопрос лишь в том как отдавать ему эту страницу в виде html или ввиде данных, которые в последствии будут рендериться через react, то как лучше?

Comment: лучше общаться с сервером через апи и не смешивать шаблоны, иначе могут возникнуть проблемы (помимо увеличения сложности архитектуры). например как навесить двухсторонний биндинг или ивенты в серверном шаблоне и связать с реактом? Только через костыли. А в целом: инструмент надо подбирать под задачу, не усложнять простого. Реакт нужен для построения сложных интерфейсов на клиенте. Если у вас такого нет, то он и не нужен. Наоборот, проблем может привнести: SEO, билдинг фронтенд приложения и т.д

Comment: Для оптимизации можно использовать SSR и отдать готовую HTML, а там реакт подхватит и будет дорисовывать уже по мере необходимости...